# Ошибка: {"code":503,"description":"JSON array is not correct"}

Tags: php, post, curl

Проверял через postman. Все работает, не понимаю, в чем причина?

**PHP**

```
<?php
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://service.sovetromantica.com/v1/animes?anime_id_array=%255B1221%255D',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Cookie: __cfduid=d32ad074e3b8e2a066e0d67c8e4f8252a1618855616'
      ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

Comment: данные надо нормально передавать CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, а не пихать в урл

Comment: вот нормально работает https://apitester.com/ ввожу post data anime_id_array=[1221], ответ [{"anime_description":"Жил-поживал один неприметный старшеклассник

Comment: @Jean-Claude спасибо большое, благодаря вам разобрался